# Output impedance function generator, limiting the current

Tags: capacitor, diodes, current-limiting, bridge-rectifier, function-generator

I've the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fngFVE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now the R of 50 ohm does limit the current that be supplied to the load. Is there a way to be independend of the 50 ohm resistor? I thought about a voltage buffer after the function generator?!

Comment: There's a lot of missing context in this question: This looks more like a full bridge rectifier. How would a voltage buffer help you in this? You told us about a schematic that you're using yet you haven't provided information as to what you're doing or why you chose this circuit.

Comment: My signal generator has an output impedance selector switch that activates or deactivates the internal resistor. Yours as well should have, I think. If not then you may need to short it "internally" or use an external buffer circuit.

Comment: Smells of an XY problem to me.

Comment: @Andyaka The problem is if I vary Rb (close to 50 ohm) the output impedance of the function generator gets annoying because the input voltage collapses (because of the high current at the output). So is there a method to buffer the function generator voltage so that the 50 ohm resistor does not effect the output voltage

Comment: Sure there is a way but why would you want to do this? XY problem is still lurking I believe.

Comment: @Andyaka Because it want to check if my mathematical model (that I made) is correct in real life. So the 50 ohm does limit that

Comment: Then why not use a simulator? Where are you going to get perfect real ideal diodes from? Like I thought it is an XY problem and I don't think you have thought this through. A better question is... I have modelled this circuit so how can I prove it is correct.